# UK Date Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that validates UK date format. I have the following:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d
```

This works great for validating: **09**/12/2011. But if the date is: **9**/12/2011 it will not validate correctly. Is there a regular expression that allows me to use a single number and two numbers for the day section? For example "**09**" and "**9**".

Comment: @Martinho: I think that LooDaFunk has demonstrated a good understanding of regexes - his regex is limited, but correct. He's stuck on one tiny detail which is exactly why people go to SO.

Comment: @Tim: I find it hard to believe that someone that can come up with that on his own, cannot at least come up with `([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d`. But then, I could be wrong.

Comment: @Martinho: I would love to learn in depth about regular expressions but I don't have the time to learn every single thing about them then come back and do a large portion of more important work

Comment: I feel like the separator segment should be the same in both places: `…([- /.])…\1…`.  Adjust numbering accordingly, or used named capture groups.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make the leading `0` optional:

```
(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d
```

You will need an additional validation step, though - this regex of course won't check for invalid dates like `31-02-2000` etc. While it's possible to do this in regex, it's not recommended because it's much easier to do this programmatically, and that regex is going to be monstrous. [Here is a date validating regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290433/regular-expression-for-aspregularexpressionvalidator-with-format-mmddyy-leap-ye/4291747#4291747) (that uses the mmddyyyy format, though) to show what I mean.

Comment: Anyway this approach it's not very correct, 49 shall be matched too.

Comment: @pooh: No, it won't. Why do you think it would?

Comment: @Tim: it will only match "49/02/2010" because there are no anchors. But then it will also match "Today is 04-02-2011."

Comment: @Martinho: Depends on how you use it - `Regex.Match()` in Java, `re.match()` in Python etc. and many validator controls implicitly anchor the regex.

Comment: @Tim: Because i've tried:) But yes, it depends on the flavor and tool.

Comment: @Tim: you're right. That comment was intended for @pooh. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

My preference goes to a combination of the simple regex, `(\d{1,2})[-/.](\d{1,2})[-/.](\d{4})`, with some code that validates that this is indeed a correct date. You will have to have that code anyways, unless you want to make a monstrous regex that rejects "29-02-2011" but not "29-02-2008".

Anyway, here's a breakdown of that regex so you can see what's going on:

- `\d{1,2}`: this part matches one or two (`{1,2}`) digits (`\d`), making up the day portion of the date.
- `[-/.]`: this matches one of the characters inside the brackets, i.e, either a `.`, a `/`, or a `-`.
- `\d{1,2}`: again, this matches one or two digits from the month.
- `[-/.]`: another separator...
- `\d{4}`: this matches exactly four (`{4}`) digits for the year portion.

Note that the day, month, and year portion of the regular expression are inside parentheses. This is to create *groups*. Each of those three portions will be captured into a group that you can retrieve from the match. Groups are identified with a number, starting with 1, from left to right. This means that the day will be group 1, the month group 2, and the year group 3. There is also a group 0 that always contains the entire text matched.

You can use the groups to perform the second part of the validation and reject invalid dates like "30-02-2011", "31-4-2011", or "32-13-2011".

If you want to reject inputs that use two different separators, like "31-12.2011", you can use a slightly more advanced feature called *backreferences*:

```
(\d{1,2})([-/.])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{4})
```

Note that now I placed the first separator inside a group. This changes the month to group 3, and the year to group 4. The separator is matched by group 2. The backreference is that `\2` part between the month and the year. It matches whatever was matched by the 2nd previous group. If you walk back two groups from the backreference you end up in group 2, the separator. If that group matched a `.`, the backreference with match only a `.` as well; if it matched a `-`, the backreference will match only a `-`; and so on.

Comment: I wish I understood why people post “breakdowns” of long regexes instead of just putting those explanations in the pattern directly via `(?x)` mode.

Comment: @tchrist: mostly because it's way less readable that way. It's inside a code block, which makes any attempt at formatting pointless, and the monospaced font makes lines much much longer.

Comment: And then I'd probably have to explain `(?x)` as well...

Comment: I’ve always found `(?x)` patterns infinitely more legible than those without.  It's also whitespace and alignment issues. I always format them carefully.  I think it helps

Answer (score 1):

What is "the UK date format" anyway?

Officially, it's 2011-02-21 today, see BS EN 28601 / ISO 8601.

On the web, you should all be using the format defined in RFC 3339.

Comment: We don't stick to rules, things are done differently.

Comment: I have never seen that example used here in real life. Real people don't enter dates into forms like that. In Britain they prefer dd/mm/yy(yy), never the US way and never year first. When using a regex to check a date format, we need to check what a user would naturally enter, not what ISO or BS or an American thinks they should enter. Certainly, internally code should manage dates in a uniform and standard way, but tell that to most programming languages! Coldfusion is particularly bad in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `{n,m}` is the quantifier that say "at least n element, max m elements". So you can write `\d{1,2}` (matches 1 or 2 digits). Complete date: `\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}`

Alternative: Make the leading zero optional:

```
0?\d/0?\d/\d{4}
```

The question mark says, that the element before the question mark is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to check for the day is to ban the `[4-9].` numbers too.

Something like `0[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[^0-9][0-9]|^[0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the similar requirements. 
Here is the complete regular expression along with Leap Year validation. 
Format: dd/MM/yyyy

(3[01]|[12]\d|0[1-9])/(0[13578]|10|12)/((?!0000)\d{4})|(30|[12]\d|0[1-9])/(0[469]|11)/((?!0000)\d{4})|(2[0-8]|[01]\d|0[1-9])/(02)/((?!0000)\d{4})|
29/(02)/(1600|2000|2400|2800|00)|29/(02)/(\d\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])

It can be easily modified to US format or other EU formats.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code, I am validating everything for the date. :-

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class FinalDateValidator {

      private Pattern pattern;
      private Matcher matcher;

      public boolean isValidDate(final String date) {
            Pattern pattern;
            Matcher matcher;
            final String DATE_PATTERN = "([0-9]{4})/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])";
            pattern = Pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN);
            matcher = pattern.matcher(date);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                matcher.reset();
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                    String month = matcher.group(2);
                    String day = matcher.group(3);

                     System.out.println("__________________________________________________");
                     System.out.println("year : "+year +"  month : "+month +" day : "+day);

                    if (day.equals("31")
                            && (month.equals("4") || month.equals("6")
                                    || month.equals("9") || month.equals("11")
                                    || month.equals("04") || month.equals("06") || month
                                    .equals("09"))) {
                        return false; // only 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 has 31 days
                    } else if (month.equals("2") || month.equals("02")) {
                        // leap year
                        if (year % 4 == 0) {
                            if (day.equals("30") || day.equals("31")) {
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                return true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (day.equals("29") || day.equals("30")
                                    || day.equals("31")) {
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

       public static void main(String argsp[]){

           FinalDateValidator vs = new FinalDateValidator();
         System.out.println("1: 1910/12/10---"+vs.isValidDate("1910/12/10"));
           System.out.println("2: 2010/2/29---"+vs.isValidDate("2010/02/29"));
           System.out.println("3: 2011/2/29---"+vs.isValidDate("2011/02/29"));
           System.out.println("3: 2011/2/30---"+vs.isValidDate("2011/02/30"));
           System.out.println("3: 2011/2/31---"+vs.isValidDate("2011/02/31"));
           System.out.println("4: 2010/08/31---"+vs.isValidDate("2010/08/31"));
           System.out.println("5: 2010/3/10---"+vs.isValidDate("2010/03/10"));
           System.out.println("6: 2010/03/33---"+vs.isValidDate("2010/03/33"));
           System.out.println("7: 2010/03/09---"+vs.isValidDate("2010/03/09"));
           System.out.println("8: 2010/03/9---"+vs.isValidDate("2010/03/9"));
           System.out.println("9: 1910/12/00---"+vs.isValidDate("1910/12/00"));
           System.out.println("10: 2010/02/01---"+vs.isValidDate("2010/02/01"));
           System.out.println("11: 2011/2/03---"+vs.isValidDate("2011/02/03"));
           System.out.println("12: 2010/08/31---"+vs.isValidDate("2010/08/31"));
           System.out.println("13: 2010/03/39---"+vs.isValidDate("2010/03/39"));
           System.out.println("14: 201011/03/31---"+vs.isValidDate("201011/03/31"));
           System.out.println("15: 2010/032/09---"+vs.isValidDate("2010/032/09"));
           System.out.println("16: 2010/03/922---"+vs.isValidDate("2010/03/922"));

       }

    }
```

Enjoy...

Comment: The person asking the question seems to be looking for a regular expression. This does not help him at all in that context.

Comment: Also 29/02/2000 is NOT a leap year