# Regex for date not working in php

Tags: php, javascript, regex

This regex working in javascript doesn't work in php once the delimiters are added, throwing out a nice error:

`$regex = '/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\\d\\d)/';`

This one neither, it even gives a compilation error!

`$regex = '/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\.- ](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/\.- ](19|20)\d{2}$/';`

Which regex do u use to validate your date in gg/mm/aaaa format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: (escaping `/` in regexp as `\/`. I also changed order of the digit match.)

```
$regex = "/^(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])\/(1[012]|0?[1-9])\/((19|20)\d{2})$/";
```

For your second regex where you used `[\/\.- ]` this is wrong because the `[\.- ]` means *'from `.` to '* to fix this `-` should be the very first or the last character between `[]`.

Comment: Pretty close!!! It doesn't validate well the day: for example 34/11/1998 is passing true.

Comment: within 34/11/1998 the match 4/11/1998 is found and return true. adding `^` and `$` to match start and end of input will fix this.

Comment: Or use a different regex delimiter when slashes are present in your regex: `$regex = "#^(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(1[012]|0?[1-9])/((19|20)\d{2})$#";`

Comment: @hysoka: Also, remember that this regex will still pass a lot of invalid dates (31/02/2011 etc.). You can do a "sanity check" with regexes, but then you should try to parse the date programmatically to see if it is valid. Regexes that really check all the leap year rules etc. are [possible but ghastly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290433/regular-expression-for-aspregularexpressionvalidator-with-format-mmddyy-leap-ye/4291747#4291747).

Comment: Here it is, thanks! That works good. Yeah I know about that, but at the moment a less strict validation of the date is enough!

Answer (score 1):

If this is for validating, why not something like this?:

```
$date = date_parse_from_format('d/m/Y', '08/08/2000');

if ($date['warning_count'] || $date['error_count']) {
   // invalid date
}
```

It's obviously not a regular expression, but it seems simpler to manage.

I'm not sure what triggers warnings and what triggers errors, but a few simple tests should satisfy any curiosities.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try this function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are attempting to escape the wrong slashes inside your string, which just makes it think you want to match backslashes but then it gets confused by the slashes inside your regex. Try this:

`"/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/((19|20)\d\d)/"`

Comment: In PHP you have to use both quotes (',") and the slashes to delimiter the regex. However, it throws out without the slashes this error: "Unknown modifier '(' in /srv/http/funlette/registerUser.php on line 40"

Comment: @hysoka44: It was more complicated than I thought. Try my new answer.

Comment: No more PHP errors, nice hit! But it allows "80/08/2000", day higher than 31 should be not allowed.

Comment: @hysoka44: You should show your actual code that has the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gabe, I solved with this one: $regex="/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/((19|20)\d\d)$/";