# How to get a valid Time range using Regular Expressions

Tags: .net, regex

How can i be able to ensure that a selected date time value is between a given time range.
i.e

```
2/2/2011 8:10:30 is invalid but
2/2/2011 8:30:00 is a valid date
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expresion?

Comment: convert to a Date and use Date.before() etc to test range

Comment: What's the allowed range, or should we guess?

Comment: Sorry an example of the allowed range is 8:30:00 to 13:00:00(1:00:00 PM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions match strings, not numbers or number ranges. Therefore you need to think about the textual representation of all valid times/dates and analyze them.

A number between 5 and 11 would therefore be `1[01]|[5-9]` etc.; this can get arbitrarily complex with dates, especially if you need to validate user input. Then your regex needs to know about leap years and all that - all of which is [possible but nightmarish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290433/regular-expression-for-aspregularexpressionvalidator-with-format-mmddyy-leap-ye/4291747#4291747) to maintain. So you really need to think about if it's really a regex you want...

For the range `8:30:00-13:00:00` you get (written here as a verbose regex):

```
\b            # start of word
(?:           # Either match...
 13:00:00     # 13:00:00
|             # or
 (?:          # hours:
  1[012]      # 10-12
  |           # or
  0?9         # 9, optional leading 0
 )            # end of hours
 :            # colon
 [0-5][0-9]   # minutes: 00-59
 :            # colon
 [0-5][0-9]   # seconds
|             # or
 0?8          # hour: (0)8
 :            # colon
 [3-5][0-9]   # minutes 30-59
 :            # colon
 [0-5][0-9]   # seconds
)             # end of alternation.
\b            # end of word
```

See why this isn't a good idea?

Comment: this is really a great answer showing why regex'es aren't always good to use, thanks for sharing this!