# Regex for MMDDYYFFFMLLLL

Tags: regex

Looking for a Regex for MMDDYYFFFMLLLL

```
MM - 01-12 (month)
DD - 01-31 (Day) 
YY - 00-99 (Year)

FFF - a-z A-Z and * (ie: JOH or LI*) 
M - a-z A-Z and * (ie: M or *)
LLLL - a-z A-Z and * (ie: SMIT or LI**)
```

Basically `FFF` is the first 3 letters of a person's first name (filled with *) 
Basically `LLLL` is the first 4 letters of a person's last name (filled with *)

I am hopeful that it would avoid 093104 as there are only 30 days in September!

Thanks

Comment: If possible, you'll be way better off just using a simple Regex (starting with `(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)...`) and then implementing the more detailed validations using application code.  Doing it all in a Regex will make your code pretty much unmaintainable.

Comment: Also, you should specify what kind of Regex language you are using.  Java and Grep are quite different, for example.

Comment: To support Felix' statement, think of the regex "logic" [required to handle leap years correctly in a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290433/regular-expression-for-aspregularexpressionvalidator-with-format-mmddyy-leap-y/4291747#4291747).

Answer (score 2):

Very straightforward, really:

```
^(?!023)(?!0229.[13579])(?!0229[02468][26])(?!0229[13579][048])(?!(0[469]|11)31)(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([0-9]{2})(?!.?[*][^*])([a-zA-Z*]{3})[a-zA-Z*](?!.{0,2}[*][^*])([a-zA-Z*]{4})$
```

(Tested.)

You asked about the numeric portion; here's an explanation of it: I trust that `(0[1-9]|1[012])` (two digits, `01` to `12`), `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` (two digits, `01` to `31`), and `([0-9]{2})` (any two digits) are straightforward enough. This matches `MMDDYY` perfectly, with the caveat that it can only enforce that `DD` is between one and thirty-one; it doesn't know that some months are shorter than that. To enforce that restriction, we preface `(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([0-9]{2})` with a series of `(?!...)` expressions, "negative lookahead assertions"; such an expression asserts that, looking forward from the specified place in the string, `...` can't be matched.

So, `^(?!023)(?!0229.[13579])(?!0229[02468][26])(?!0229[13579][048])(?!(0[469]|11)31)` ensures that the string doesn't start with a substring that matches `023` (February thirty-somethingth), `0229.[13579]` (February twenty-ninth in an odd year), `0229[02468][26]` (February twenty-ninth in an even year in an even decade that is nonetheless not a leap-year, e.g. 2006), `(?!0229[13579][048])` (February twenty-ninth in an even year in an odd decade that is nonetheless not a leap-year, e.g. 2014), or `(0[469]|11)31` (April, June, September, or November thirtieth). This rules out all the values of `DD` that are between one and thirty-one but that are nonetheless invalid.

Note that this assumes that `00` refers to the year `2000`. The rule is that any multiple of four is a leap year, *except* that multiples of one hundred are *not* leap years *unless* they're multiples of four hundred. So `1900` was not a leap year, and `2100` won't be a leap year, but `2000` *is*. The above regex treats `00` as a leap year.

Comment: This will be used in JavaScript.

Can you explain the expression?

Comment: @user1207485: I can, if you want, but are you sure you really want to use it? I mean, if someone inputs `093104JOH*SMIT`, do you really intend to just tell them "Invalid input" without giving any way to determine that the problem is the invalid date? I posted the regex half-jokingly: that's the simplest regex that enforces your requirements, and as you can see, it's quite a doozy. (The "very straightforward" was 100% joking.)

Comment: First let me say THANK YOU.  I appreciate the help.  But I was just curious about certain points in the regex expression.  The alpha portion is not too much trouble to understand, but the numeric portion seems hard to follow (I have never really used regex much).

Comment: @user1207485: You're welcome! I've added an explanation of the numeric portion.