# Regular expression with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

what is problem with the following pattern ??

```
~(?P<day>[1-9]{1,2})[.](?P<month>[1-9]{1,2})[.](?P<year>[0-9]{1,4})~
```

i want to allow following formats..

```
21.12.2012
21.8.2012 // not 21.08.2012
```

but it also allows..

```
2012.12.12
12.12.12
```

Please help...

Thank you,
Hardik

Comment: So you don't want to allow leading zeroes? Only in the month part or also in the day part? Your specifications are rather vague. Also, why not allow leading zeroes in the first place?

Comment: yes also in day part... 03.12.2012 should not be allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the regex. Also, if you only want to allow four-digit years, you have to make that explicit:

```
~^(?P<day>[0-9]{1,2})[.](?P<month>[0-9]{1,2})[.](?P<year>[0-9]{4})$~
```

`^` and `$` only match at the start and end of the string, ensuring that your regex doesn't match the `12.12.12` substring in `2012.12.12`.

If you want to forbid leading zeroes, use

```
~^(?P<day>[1-9][0-9]?)[.](?P<month>[1-9][0-9]?)[.](?P<year>[0-9]{4})$~
```

Of course, this doesn't do any sanity checking (99.99.9999 passes this regex), but checking for a valid date is something [you shouldn't be doing with a regex anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4291747/20670).

Comment: thank you for your answer but still allows 12.12.12 and 12.12.1 how can i restrict it ??

Comment: @Hardik: No, it doesn't. Did you really change the `{1,4}` part (meaning 1-4 repetitions of the previous token) into `{4}` (meaning exactly 4 repetitions)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$regex = '#^[0-9]{2}.[1-9][0-9]{0,1}.[0-9]{4}$#';
```

It should allow the 2 first formats, not the others.