# Why can't you define your own custom charclasses in Regexes?

Tags: javascript, regex, pcre

I mean, instead of

```
/^[asdfjkl;]foo[asdfjkl;]bar[asdfjkl;]baz$/i
```

Or even

```
RegExp('^[[:HOMEROW:]]foo[[:HOMEROW:]]bar[[:HOMEROW:]]baz$'.replace(/\[:HOMEROW:]/g, 'asdfjkl;'))
```

I might just be able to write:

```
/\H=[asdfjkl;];^\Hfoo\Hbar\Hbaz$/
```

### How has nobody thought of this, and assuming they have, why does it not enjoy more support or implementation?

#### Note: I'm more interested in the philosophical aspects of this: what's the rationale for excluding the feature?

Comment: Could you simplify your regex?

Comment: *"I'm more interested in the philosophical aspects of this"*, which makes it not well suited for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're asking a philosophical question (which are not really good questions for a site like SO), let me try to give a rather conjectural answer. After all, I can't speak for the language designers, but I can guess:

Usually, when a regex becomes as monstrous as this, it's a reliable sign that a regex is not the right tool for the job. So in a way, custom character classes would encourage bad programming (like trying to validate an e-mail address with a regex). I suspect that's why nobody who is smart enough to define a regex standard has opted to implement this functionality.

For example, if your goal is to find e-mail addresses, then it's probably best to do a very rudimentary scan with a basic regex like

```
\S+@\S+\.\S+
```

and then looking at the results with a dedicated e-mail address parser to weed out/trim the mismatches.

A better example might be date validation:

You *can* validate a MM/DD/YYYY date using the regex

```
^(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])\/31)|(?:(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:29|30)))\/(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})|(?:0?2\/29\/(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\/(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))$
```

but you probably should rather use a regex like

```
^\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d$
```

and use a date parser to figure out valid dates in a second step.

Comment: I know that this is a subjective answer to a subjective question, so I can accept a downvote, but I would like to hear the reason for it, if possible.

Comment: Lol, did you just crank out that MM/DD/YYYY regex off the top of your head, or was it copypasta? I like your answer, but it seems like the `:parent` pseudoselector in CSS -- specifiers and implementors shouldn't intentionally constrain devs "for their own good".

Comment: @adlwalrus: I copied that from an [earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290433/regular-expression-for-aspregularexpressionvalidator-with-format-mmddyy-leap-y/4291747#4291747) (which I specifically wrote to demonstrate why regexes are not suitable for all purposes they can theoretically be used for)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a wrapper object for RegExp:

```
myRegExp = function(regex,mods) {
    var customclasses = {
        nonDotLocalChar:'A-Za-z0-9!#$%&\'*+-/=?^_`{|}~'
    }, i;
    for( i in customclasses) {
        regex = regex.replace(new RegExp("\[:(\^?)"+i+":\]","i"),"$1"+customclasses[i]);
    }
    return new RegExp(regex,mods);
};
```

You can then use the above like so:

```
var eam = new myRegExp("^[[:nondotlocalchar:]](?(?:[[:nondotlocalchar:]].........");
```

You can also use it like:

```
new myRegExp("[[:^nondotlocalchar:]]"); // negates the custom class
new myRegExp("[@[:nondotlocalchar:]]"); // allow anything from the custom class, or the @ character
```

Comment: I'm more interested in the historical/philosophical explanations for it not being supported natively -- it would go a long way toward readability and composability. What's the rationale for making us do this kind of stuff?

Comment: By that reasoning, everything in jQuery should be available natively. Not that that'd be a good thing, but do you see what I'm saying? JavaScript gives you the building blocks, and you have to take those blocks and build a house out of them.

Comment: That would probably be great! I mean, regexes are builtins and DOM is the host/environment, so not exactly true, but if the DOM were replaced by jQuery, I'm sure that many would jump for joy!