# Regex expression for M/d/yyyy

Tags: c#, regex

my string format are in M/d/yyyy. Which means there will be no zero in front of the month and date digit. 
example: 9/23/2012, 7/9/2012 etc

I have tried:

> ^((((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]).-/.-/)|((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30).-/.-/)|((0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[.-/]0?2.-/)|(29[.-/]0?2.-/))|(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[13578]|1[02])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)(0[13456789]|1[012])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])02((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|(2902((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)|00))))$

but i guess this is for d/M/yyyy.

Anyone have the expression for M/d/yyyy?

Comment: That regex ought to be taken out and shot. It's riddled with errors. Regex is not the correct tool for date validation. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4291747/20670)

Comment: Try `DateTime.Parse`, Your code will be easier to read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression for asp:RegularExpressionValidator with format MMddyy (leap year issue)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290433/regular-expression-for-aspregularexpressionvalidator-with-format-mmddyy-leap-y)

Comment: You have tried and you guess for what it is? A regex like this can't be read by anyone. If you use regex in this length, write them in a readable manner, see my blog post: [Do you write readable regexes?](http://wp.me/p2pTzU-V). And Tim is correct, regex is not the correct tool for this job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are trying to validate if the Date is in format `M/d/yyyy` then [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) is a better solution then Regex. Something like.

```
string str = "9/23/2012";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(str,
                          "M/d/yyyy",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, 
                          out dt))
{
    //valid date
}
else
{
    //Invalid date
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this expression

> ^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])|[1-9])/(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|(1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1]))/(([0-9]{2})|([1-9][0-9]{3}))$

you can find more from [this site](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5)

Comment: Hi Rustem, an answer should be more than just a link to an external site. What if that page is relocated or the site goes away? You should at least quote the suitable regex you found there (while of course still linking to its source). If you can find a suitable regex there.

Comment: Thanks! However, that regex is very bad. It allows dates like `0.0.0000` and doesn't allow dates like `09/15/2012`...

Answer (score -1):

thanks for all your reply, you all helped me. The expression to my qns is:

```
^([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Try it with the string `01.|0/0000`. And of course all kinds of invalid dates like `2/31/9999`.