# Regular Expression for Date Format : dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: asp.net

I want to check the date which must be in the format `dd-mm-yyyy` using a regular expression, and it also must check the leap year dates.

I am using `RegularExpressionValidator` for checking the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression-

```
^(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))-((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31-((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)-((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))-((20[0-9][0-9]))|(29-02-20(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))$
```

Got it from [Here](http://www.regexlib.com/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score 2):

try this. It works for me!

```
ValidationExpression="(^((((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))|([1-9]))-(((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))|([1-9]))-(([0-9]{2})|(((19)|([2]([0]{1})))([0-9]{2}))))$)"
```

Comment: Only answer the worked for me, tried the others, didn't work, ty!

Answer (score 1):

This regex also handles leap year:

> ^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(0[13578]|1[02])/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)/(0[13456789]|1[012])/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])/02/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29/02/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$

Matches
[29/02/2000], [30/04/2003], [01/01/2003]

Non-Matches
[29/02/2001], [30-04-2003], [1/1/1899]

You can also check this link out: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/LengthValidation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can **javascript** to check leap year [for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175521/javascript-to-find-leap-year)

```
isLeap = new Date(year, 1, 29).getMonth() == 1
```

**Regular Expression**

```
^(?:^(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])/31)|(?:(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])/(?:29|30)))/(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})|(?:0?2/29/(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))/(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])/(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))$)$
```

These allow but do not require a leading zero in single-digit months/days. If you don't want that, replace all instances of 0? with 0.

Comment: Parsing dates with regular expressions is possible, but frustrating. It's hard to get right, the expression is difficult for non-regex wizards to understand (which means it's difficult to prove that the thing is correct), and it is slow compared to other options.

Comment: see  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290433/regular-expression-for-aspregularexpressionvalidator-with-format-mmddyy-leap-y) if you dont have any option

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) and have the client-side validation be simple and on the server-side use a DateTime.TryParse to get a definitive validation. Although I suspect you don't need your code to work all the way to the year 9999 (no, I couldn't immediately see if the supplied regexes work that far into the future).

Answer (score 0):

from Microsoft DN but modified to work with years both 20xx and 19xx to used as DOB

```
^(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31-((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)-((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))/((((20[0-9][0-9]))|(29-02-20(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))|(((19[0-9][0-9]))|(29-02-19(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))))$
```

Answer (score -1):

**for dd/MM/yyyy formate**

```
(((0|1)[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/((19|20)\d\d))$
```

Comment: How come anything before 1900 and after 2099 is an invalid date?

Comment: implement your own logic

change the number in place of number you see and check its working or not