# Extract date in a string C#?

Tags: c#, regex, windows, string, date

What is the good solution for extracting a date which is given in a string?

For example:

`string block = "This should try to get a date 2005-10-26";
  //TODO! I WANT THE DATE`

Any good tips for me?

Regex maybe?

Comment: Yes, regex, but we need more info. Are you only looking for `yyyy-mm-dd` dates?  Would you mind if the regex matched `1234-56-78`?

Comment: Does the string always have the same pattern ?

Comment: yes yyyy-mm-dd format, sorry I should have mentioned that! But I want to restrict it to month as we have it and the day too. The string may have different pattern, we want to only check if we have a date, extract it.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest regex would be

```
new Regex(@"\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b")
```

but this doesn't do any error checking and only finds *exactly*  that format.

If you want to do date validation, regex is not your best friend here. It's possible, but best left to a date parser, [unless you want render suicidal whoever has to read your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4291747/20670) six months from now. I would agree to a basic sanity check, but don't attempt to validate leap years etc.:

```
new Regex(@"\b\d{4}-(?:1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])\b")
```

Comment: Thanks man! :D That should be more sufficient for my program. Thanks!

Comment: It might also be prudent to match 1 or 2 digit month/days. `@"\b\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\b"`.

Comment: @Romoku: He explicitly said he only wants to match two-digit months/days.

Comment: I am simply offering a suggestion since it is common to have months/days without the leading zero. If he doesn't find it useful then he doesn't need to use it.

Comment: @Romoku: Oh, absolutely. Sorry if my reply sounded dismissive, that was not my intention.