# Validate date format(F j, Y, g:i a) using regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to validate date `Format: date("F j, Y, g:i a");   // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm` using regular expression.

Comment: Do you mean validate the format, or check whether it's a valid date?

Comment: Date should be in above specified format..

Comment: Ok, you want it, but do you have a question?

Comment: What are the constraints? Would you care if the regex matched `February 29, 3000, 12:16 pm` or `April 31, 1050, 13:61 am`?

Comment: yes, I want to validate format as well as date.

Comment: @AmolBansode If you want to validate a date, why not use a date library?

Comment: [Don't use a regex to validate a date](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4291747/20670). Use a regex (like @aelor's) to *find* a date or to do a quick sanity check, then use a date library to try and *parse* the string to see if it's actually a valid date. You'll need to do that step anyway.

Comment: @Biffen,Yes, I can but I want to validate using regular expression, having some purpose behind this

Comment: @AmolBansode Accounting for leap years, leap seconds, pre-gregorian dates, days in months, etc. makes for a *huge* regex. I'd say you should seriously reconsider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QRegularExpression re("[A-Z][a-z]+ \\d{2}, \\d{4}, \\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2} (?:am|pm)");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match("March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm");
bool hasMatch = match.hasMatch();
```

Comment: How would this code handle `"Spam 99, 4321, 99:99 pm"`?

Comment: the op should either take the risk or hardcode all months inside the regex.